# Pass nested class by reference as parameter in unit test method

Tags: c#, web-services, unit-testing, soap, accessor

So I'm trying to dive into Unit Testing, specifically for web services (SOAP versions), and am having incredible difficulty in getting the appropriate format for passing the referenced nested class OtherClass.aNestedClass.

As you can see below, both of the classes OtherClass and aNestedClass are public. The method readDB is the target method for the unit test. However, when I attempt to declare an instance of OtherClass, I only get the option of OtherClass_Accessor, which makes the readDB method call none too happy (specifically I get the 'The best overloaded match for ... has some invalid arguments' error).

How do I go about correctly passing a class by reference as a parameter to a unit test's accessor method call?

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void readDB(ref OtherClass.aNestedClass oa)
    {
        oa.A = "abc";
        oa.B = "def";
    }
}

public class OtherClass
{
    public class aNestedClass
    {
        public string A;
        public string B;
    }
}
```

My sample attempt:

```
[TestMethod()]
[HostType("ASP.NET")]
[AspNetDevelopmentServerHost("D:\\MyProject", "/MyProject")]
[UrlToTest("http://localhost/MyProject/default.aspx")]
public void readDBTest()
{
    OtherClass_Accessor.aNestedClass oa = new OtherClass_Accessor.aNestedClass();

    readDB(ref oa);

    // assert statements...
}
```

Comment: I suppose this is too much to hope for, but does it really have to be a nested class?  Nesting will pretty much prevent you from using it outside the class, because it's not in-scope outside of the class.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, since the original developer of these web services used that structure to pass various bits of data throughout the web services. They're very much embedded.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter in `readDB()` is specifying a `type`, not a parameter variable. Try this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void readDB(ref OtherClass.aNestedClass myNestedClassInstance)
    {
        //do some DB reading, modify strings in class passed by ref.
    }
}
```

Comment: That was my fault. I did not include the variable name in my sample code structure. I edited the original post to include such, with a sample of how it is referenced in the method as well.